# I don't understand how processing.js works

Tags: processing.js

Does the javascript in the processing.js script find the script type="application/processing" and convert it to javascript?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at the basic example located here:

http://processingjs.org/source/basic-example/processingjs_basic-example.html

Then no it isn't. That special script tag handling is actually in:

http://processingjs.org/source/basic-example/processing.init.js

Which is not part of main package but is in the examples package as examples/init.js

Comment: Is that the concept? Does it convert the processing script in the page into javascript and then run it?

Comment: Let me ask the question a different way. I'm new to Processing. Is the syntax of Processing well formed javascript. If so, then the implementation is primarily righting functions. If not, then some translation must be required. I'm trying to figure out whether translation is necessary.

Comment: Basically it's the Processing programming language originally designed for Java. Processing.js ports that language to run via Javascript and uses a Canvas tag for the renderings. So the direct answer is no it is not Javascript and translation is required at run-time.

Comment: Was I able to answer your questions?

Answer (score 1):

Since the processingjs does have support for events and since the only real job is to have a canvas and a function to load your .pde with i'd say it's quite easy going. As for support just view the learning tab at processing.org it's a lot of useful examples there.

As for java .pde it's a fully object-event-oriented environment where you can create any object you can think of and load any graphical components you can produce by means of the preload method provided in processingjs. By creating an instance of processing in your javascript you can add and control any data-maniputation that you require in your processing .pde and by creating an interface in the .pde you can call any external javascript you may need. I'd say if you are crafty with your JS you can decide how much work you want to do where (java resp. javascript). As for environment the processing-ide [processing-ide](http://processing.org/reference/environment/) allows for syntax-highlighting and parsing of your scripts and an easy way to add your graphical data. Since your .pde file will be compiled to JS during runtime you can actually se the interpretation of your .pde-class or something that you did (if you use firebug..).

As for animations you can chose to not loop and omit framerate to just present a static picture that you can dynamically alter by means of rewrite. That kind of image-processing is kind of powerful. This means that your canvas can be populated with data at runtime by a user or a service. This is powerful since it allows for some really cool things. Like this: [cool stuff](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/) and let's say it supports some cool rendering-modes: processingjs.org/articles/RenderingModes.html.

As for the java-part it's rare that you only use JS in your web-app. I mean it might be dynamic content produced through JS, Java, PHP, XML, JSON, HTML, CSS some framework (Play, JSF, Rails) all at once so i wouldn't mind the java-part (it's well documented :))

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Processing.js includes a compiler, if you want to use the Processing language.

When you use it as an embedded script, then it does exactly as you describe.

http://processingjs.org/reference/articles/p5QuickStart#processingcodeinwebpage